# Issue in downloading file through hyperlink in chrome but working fine in Explorer

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I'm Facing problem with anchor tag. The hyperlink working fine with IE (the files gets downloaded when clicked). But the hyperlink is not working when opening with chrome (files not get downloaded). Please help to rectify this issue.

Comment: You'll need to give us a bit more detail than that if you want any answers.... For a start, where is your code?

Comment: <a href="file://ton-srv-06/Toansausers/Reports/IMS-13/Audit%20Plan/Anual%20IMS%20Plan-2015.pdf" target="_blank" title="">Annual IMS Audit Plan 2015 </a>

Comment: Please give solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Chrome's security model:

> The security model of Chrome prevents/blocks the user from being able
>   to open file:// links when the user selects (left clicks) the link, or
>   selects to open them in a new window (middle click)

If you want your users to download these links then either they will have to install an extension such as [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida), or you'll need to create a link from within your application (and you have tagged your question with asp.net, so I'm assuming you have one) which can forward the file to the user.